# How long did it take, at a minimum, to prep a shuttle for launch after it landed?

Tags: space-shuttle

The [Space Shuttle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle) relied on a pair of [SRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster)s, and fuel supplement in the [External Tank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_external_tank) for it's launch.

Assuming Payload, Service parts/consumables, Crews, SRBs, and ET were ready -

- How long did it take, at a minimum, to prep a shuttle for launch after it landed?
- Were the shuttles capable of back-to-back missions?

Comment: Do you mean "One shuttle in orbit, another being prepared on the ground"?

Comment: @SF. No; I meant re-launch after landing _subject_ to the caveats mentioned apropos crew, essential servicing, SRB et.c

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is hard to say what *might* be possible, but we can certainly look at what was actually done.  The fastest turnaround time in the Program's history was 54 days by Atlantis in 1985.  I suspect that would not be possible with some of the new procedures put into place post-Challenger.

It seems Columbia did it the fastest post-Challenger: 88 days.  I believe SSME inspection is the long-pole in this process.  Even if you just replace the SSMEs, you still have a lot to do.

Answer (score 7):

Supplemental answer to this un-addressed part of the question "Were the shuttles capable of back-to-back missions?"

It happened throughout the program. More frequently early on as orbiters were introduced into the fleet and others went in for maintenance.

- The first five flights were back-to-back missions of Columbia
  (OV-102).
- The next three flights were back-to-back missions of Challenger
  (OV-099).
- The 10th and 11th flights were back-to-back missions of Challenger.
- The 14th, 15th, and 16th flights were back-to-back missions of
  Discovery (OV-103).
- The 35th and 36th flights were back-to-back missions of Discovery.
- The 91st and 92nd flights were back-to-back missions of Discovery.
- The 98th and 99th flights were back-to-back missions of Atlantis
  (OV-104).
- The 114th and 115th flights were back-to-back missions of Discovery.
- Endeavour (OV-105) never flew back-to-back missions.
- The shortest interval on a back-to-back mission was 63 days, between
  mission 10 (STS-41B) and mission 11 (STS-41C), using Challenger.
- The longest interval on a back-to-back mission was almost a year, during the recovery from the STS-107 accident. These (STS-114 and STS-121, both flown by Discovery) were the last back-to-back missions in the program.

Comment: Thanks for the correction to whoever supplied it! Much appreciated.

Comment: But the Shuttle Atlantis had a shorter time between two starts, 55 days between 10.03.85 and 11.27.85. This was not a back to back mission, the start of Challenger at 19.30.85 was in between. Most intervals between two starts of the same Shuttle were substantialy longer than 100 days.

Comment: @Uwe the other answer describes that turnaround.  I was only talking about back-to-back missions.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest intervals below 100 days between two starts of the same Shuttle were:

- 55 days between 10.03.85 and 11.27.85 for Atlantis
- 63 days between 02.03.84 and 04.06.84 for Challenger
- 66 days between 04.12.85 and 06.17.85 for Discovery
- 70 days between 08.30.84 and 11.08.84 for Discovery
- 71 days between 06.17.85 and 08.27.85 for Discovery
- 73 days between 06.18.83 and 08.30.83 for Challenger
- 75 days between 04.04.83 and 06.18.83 for Challenger
- 77 days between 01.25.85 and 04.12.85 for Discovery
- 78 days between 11.08.84 and 01.25.85 for Discovery
- 88 days between 11.08.84 and 01.25.85 for Columbia
- 90 days between 10.30.85 and 01.28.86 for Challenger
- 91 days between 04.29.85 and 07.29.85 for Challenger
- 93 days between 07.29.85 and 10.30.85 for Challenger
- 97 days between 03.22.82 and 06.27.82 for Columbia