# Building space stations with the original, smaller shuttle

Tags: space-shuttle, space-station, orbital-assembly

In [an answer to a recent question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24215/90) we see a plan for many space stations as part of a space infrastructure, with a surface-to-low-Earth-orbit reusable shuttle as another part.  This shuttle eventually turned into what became the space shuttle.  As far as I understand, the initial design specified a cargo bay 12 feet wide and 40 feet long.  Due to [involvement of the Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_design_process#Air_Force_involvement) this was changed to a design with 15 feet width and 60 feet length.

Looking at the [modules of the ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_of_the_International_Space_Station#Assembly_sequence) we see that many modules have a diameter of 4 meter or more (12 feet = ~3.6 meter).  Also many modules where launched by the space shuttle.

Assuming the smaller shuttle with a smaller cargo bay would have been built and used, I guess space station modules with a maximal diameter of 12 feet would have been kind of an issue (think of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daYqk.jpg) but with 1 meter less space).

**Would have these planned stations be built in the same way the ISS was built, by sending up -smaller- modules with a shuttle to be linked in space, or by sending smaller parts (walls) with a shuttle?** Or were there other means of getting these stations up planned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A mix of manned shuttle missions and unmanned boosters carrying larger modules.  They planned to use Saturn Vs to launch pre-assembled stations (like Skylab) and have the shuttles bring up experiment and logistics modules.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This whole report is available [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19700026519.pdf) but the illustrations are poorly reproduced in black-and-white.

Comment: Let's not forget the [Wet Workshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_workshop) - using the spent fuel tanks of the shuttle as structure of habitats/modules, filling them with equipment delivered separately.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to the Shuttle approach, there were really two modes of station building.

Skylab first, which used a Saturn-IVB third stage outfitted before launch, and was basically all done in a single launch.  (Dry workshop. Wet workshop idea was launch it full of fuel with a big payload and have the stuff submerged in the fuel/oxidizer).

Salyut/Mir second, used a module approach, but the key technology was a maneuvering system, small enough to attach to a module, that did not detract from the total payload. For Pirs/Poisk at ISS this was a modified Progress. Proton launched modules had their own maneuvering systems.

Had the shuttle payload bay not been big enough, no doubt big modules would have been launched on a Titan or Atlas and maneuvered to dock. Or else Shuttle-C style approaches where a singular large payload would be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to think: The modules were designed to fit into the shuttle - had it been smaller, the modules itself would probably been designed smaller (so still to fit the shuttle) - perhaps limiting its use, but had the shuttle been larger, I'd bet my money the modules (at least some of them) might even been larger...